# Exisiting Umbraco Umbraco v6.0.5 site throws No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, umbraco

I have an existing Umbraco v6.0.5 (Assembly version: 1.0.4869.18012) site which I built.

I got a new PC the other day and up until now, all my .NET projects have run fine on it.

I have loaded up the same code from the Umbraco site that is already working in production **and** on my old PC.

The site now throws: **No parameterless constructor defined for this object** when I hit a controller which inherits: **RenderMvcController**

Yes, this controller has no parameterless constructor as I use ninject to inject an interface into the following code:

```
public SignupController(ISignupManager signupManager)
{
    _signupManager = signupManager;
}
```

As I said, this code worked before and nothing has changed as I just did a fresh checkout of the working code from my SVN repo.

Any ideas would be great. Things to remember:

- I got a new machine and I am running all of the same tools that I used on my old machine
- The code is proven working code
- I am using Umbraco v6.0.5 (Assembly version: 1.0.4869.18012)
- The CMS and content and templates etc.. are from a copy of the live database so it's all the same.

I am thinking that either I may be missing some thing that umbraco needs or my dependency injection is not firing.

Here is my stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
at ASP._Page_Views_Donate_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Projects\Biggest Game Of Cricket\trunk\Umbraco\Views\Donate.cshtml:line 9
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

RuSs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code is *exactly* the same, then it will be a machine configuration issue. Do you have both MVC3 and MVC4 installed?

However, it does sound like something is not registering correctly. I know you say that this is a fresh/clean checkout but that doesn't necessarily mean that everything was checked-in that needed to be :)

I would check that the same bin folder contents exist between projects and also that your dependency registration code is present/correct in both projects. It sounds possible that your global.asax file isn't using the Ninject registration code or is using it incorrectly.

Whether that means that there is a DLL reference missing (e.g. MVC4) or whether the global.asax markup is inheriting from the from class.

Comment: This worked for me. If you are using 2013, you can right click on your solution and choose "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution". You should look for any duplicates. This can save time over going through each reference's version property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Ninject.Web.MVC DLL was the wrong version on my local. just took me a whole day to find this. thansk @Digbyswift

Comment: I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 application which we recently integrated with Umbraco 7. Inside the global.asax.cs file of the MVCApplication, there is a CreateKernel() method were the repository and servicemodules are registered. Since Umbraco doesn't use the Global.asax, I am not sure how and where to use that method. I am really interested on how you use Ninject on your Umbraco project.